# Upgrading to PostgreSQL 11: set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, lateral

The following query stopped working when upgrading from PostgreSQL 9.6 to 11:

```
with doc as (select * from documents where name = doc_id)

select jsonb_array_elements_text(permissions)
from users
where users.name = user_name

union

select 
  case 
    when doc.reader = user_name then 'read'
    when doc.owner = user_name then unnest(array['read','write'])
    else unnest(array[]::text[])
    end 
from doc;
```

The `union` as usual *puts together* two lists of values, both lists can have zero, one or more elements.

The first `select` can return zero, one or more just because that's what's in the `users` table.

The second `select` always scans one row from the `documents` table, but returns zero, one or more rows depending on what the `case` decides.

PostgreSQL 9.6 was working as expected, PostgreSQL 11 says:

```
ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE
LINE 56:    else unnest(array[]::text[])
                 ^
HINT:  You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
```

I appreciate the advice, but I can't figure out how to use a `LATERAL FROM` here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hint is a bit misleading here. As it says, adding lateral joins to your set-returning functions *might* help (in general), but I don't think it makes much sense in your case.

You can easily work around this by changing the `CASE` expression to return an array, and then unnesting the result:

```
...
select 
  unnest(
    case 
      when doc.reader = user_name then array['read']
      when doc.owner = user_name then array['read','write']
      else array[]::text[]
    end
  )
from doc;
```